# Need help in adding a php variable within HREF as a target link please

Tags: php, html, url

I'm trying to add this php variable `<?php echo ($_GET["w"]); ?>`

(where w = a unique short URL passed on as a URL suffix, eg, example.com/?&w=http://bit.ly/FT9d, and i need to pick up this unique URL string to display on the page)

Within a HTML file as a target link for a href value, like this -

```
Visit your personal microsite <a href="<?php echo ($_GET["w"]) ;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo ($_GET["w"]); ?></a>
```

The idea is to Display the Unique URL passed along in the original page URL (which it does) and also to link the unique URL displayed to the actual unique URL.

Supposing the unique URL passed along is www.youtube.com as an example,

It is displaying properly in the frontend like this -

Visit your Corporate Microsite today www.youtube.com

But the target URL of this is showing up as -

http://example.com/www.youtube.com

(example.com being where this page is hosted)

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Basically both the variables values, the target link and the displayed link need to be the same.

Searched for a solution but mostly came up with PHP examples, not many examples of adding this small php variable WITHIN a HTML file.

Can anyone please guide me how to add this so that the unique URL shown and targeted are the same? `<a href="uniqueURL">UniqueURL</a>`

And this unique URL can be added by a php variable get string like `<?php echo ($_GET["w"]); ?>`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET["w"]`? can you put it in your code?

Comment: It will be unique for every user that receives and clicks that link Anant, it will be passed on to the user in the URL as a suffix..

Comment: As far as only showing the value is concerned, it is showing correctly, but the target link automatically gets prefixed by the domain name where this HTML page is hosted. BTW I have renamed the page to example.php from example.html

Comment: Using `$_GET` in your application output without making it safe will render you vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

use the below code: 
Visit your personal microsite `<a href="<?php echo ($_GET['w']) ;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo ($_GET['w']); ?></a>`

You cannot have double inverted commas inside another double inverted commas, instead use single inverted commas inside double inverted commas

Comment: It's worth getting into the habit, if you see `$_GET` used in web application output, to point out the XSS vulnerability. Someone could render malicious JavaScript here, just by sending a link.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried using single quote but it didn't work, the target still showed up as example.com/www.youtube.com

But I found the solution and it was totally unexpected.

In the original page URL where i was adding the unique URL as a suffix, i was adding it as -

http://example.com/?w=www.youtube.com

And when I used `<?php echo ($_GET['w']) ;?>` in place of the URL, this made my target URL as -

http://example.com/www.youtube.com

But when I tried changing the original page URL to -

http://example.com/?w=http://youtube.com

replacing 'www.' with 'http://'

The target URL is perfect - http://youtube.com

Maybe something to do with www. being takes as a subdomain.

Thanks a lot guys. This is a very unlikely situation but hope this helps someone :)